# Scaping text from webpage using 'rvest' and SelectorGadget

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to get a text from a webpage. To simplify my question, let me use @RonakShah's Stackoverflow account as an example to extract the reputation value. With 'SelectorGadget' showing "div, div", I used the following code:

```r
library(rvest)
so <- read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah') %>%
  html_nodes("div") %>% html_nodes("div") %>% html_text()
```

This gave an object `so` with as many as 307 items.

Then, I turned the object into a dataframe:

```
so <- as.data.frame(so)
view(so)
```

Then, manually gone through all items in the dataframe until finding the correct value `so$so[69]`. My question is how to quickly find the specific target value. In my real case, it is a little more complicated for doing it manually as there are multiple items with the same values and I need to identify the correct order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a specific tag and it the respective class closer to your target. You can find that using selector gadget.

```
library(rvest)

read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah') %>%
  html_nodes("div.grid--cell.fs-title") %>%
  html_text() 

#[1] "254,328"
```

---

As far as scraping StackOverflow is concerned it has an API to get the information about users/question/answers. In R, there is a wrapper package around it called [stackr](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) (not on CRAN) which makes it very easy.

```
library(stackr)
data <- stack_users(3962914)
data$reputation
[1] 254328
```

`data` has lot of other information as well about the user.

`3962914` is the user id of the user you are interested in which can be found out from their profile link. (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962914/ronak-shah`).

Comment: SO was just an example website.

Comment: It works perfectly now for my work. I am still getting familiar with Selector Gadget to select what I want. It is a useful tool. Really appreciate your help!